# Помогите улучшить if (много раз по "строка not in другая строка")

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь улучшить качество своего кода, но застрял.

IF выводит строку_х если в ней не встречаются варианты подстрок с 1 по n-ю. Т.е. строка_х может содержать еще какие то символы кроме варианта, но если он внутри есть то не надо его печатать.

Код:

```
if "i_need_this_in" in string_x and \
        "variant_1" not in string_x and \
        "variant_2" not in string_x: # и тут их много...
    print(string_x)
```

И он даже работает. Но уж очень примитивно =(

По идее я могу сделать как то так:

```
variants = ["variant_1", "variant_2"] # и.т.д.
do_print = True

if "i_need_this_in" in string_x:
    for variant in variants:
        if variant in string_x:
            do_print = False
            break

    if do_print:
        print(string_x)
```

Но есть чувство, что иду куда то не туда и можно как то проще. Однако, то ли гугл сломался, то ли день такой, но ничего похожего я не нашел =(.

PS если кому вдруг такое придет в голову:
Все имена переменных и текст в кавычках в коде вымышлены, любые совпадения с реальными переменными, строками или комментариями случайны.

PPS `"Вариант" not in string and "вариант" not in string` же равны `"ариант" not in string`?

Comment: `if "i_need_this_in" in string_x and all(v not in string_x for v in variants):`. И нет, не равно: все еще может быть подстрока "1ариант" или что-то такое.

Comment: Ага, т.е. оно будет работать. Нет, 1ариант не ожидается, спасибо. Вау, как просто... в одну строку... Спасибо!
PS делать все строчными как то так?: `...in string_x.lower`?

Comment: Сделать строчными при проверке на вхождение? `v.lower() not in string_x for v in variants`. PS Ну и все еще может быть "бариант".

Comment: Ага, так. Спасибо. Хотя скорее `v not in string_x.lower() for v in variants` т.к. варианты задаю я, а стринг_Хы берется из извне. PS Как ответ оформишь? Или не хочешь заморачиваться?

Comment: Если хочешь, сам напиши